# Algolia not indexing related entities when updating in Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, search, methods, algolia

I have a product entity which has 6 properties that should be indexed by Algolia (name, slug, description, categories, supermarkets, image).

When I create a new product everything works correctly and is indexed how it should be as shown below:

```
{
  "name": "White Bread",
  "slug": "white-bread",
  "description": "This is a description",
  "image": "logo.png",
  "supermarkets": [
    "Unassigned",
    "Unassigned"
  ],
  "categories": [
    "Bread",
    "Unassigned"
  ],
  "objectID": "eyJpZCI6MX0="
}
```

However if I go and specifically edit either the supermarkets and categories and then save it, they are not indexed to algolia upon saving. However if I change any of the other properties such as the name then the changes I made to categories or supermarkets are then updated to the algolia index.

This is my method for getting categories from within my product:

```
/**
 * @Algolia\Attribute(algoliaName="supermarkets")
 */
public function getSupermarkets()
{
    $supermarkets = array();

    foreach($this->instances as $instance){
        $supermarkets[] = $instance->getSupermarketName();
    }

    return $supermarkets;
}
```

Would be grateful if anyone has a fix for this or any suggestions, I thought it might be because the supermarkets and categories come from another entity which is not indexed but haven't managed to find a fix yet.

Thanks

Comment: Please, post code instead of pictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you are using `algolia/algolia-search-bundle` which would utilize Doctrine Event Subscriber to index your entity.

When you edit your entity's fields that are stored directly on the entity itself, the doctrine subscriber is invoked, and that causes your indexes to get updated.

However, when you update related entities, the subscriber on the main entity is not invoked. You need to cause the subscriber on the main entity to do its thing, which will update your indexes.

I would suggest creating doctrine event subscribers for updates on related  entities, and triggering custom event whenever a category, or a supermarket is updated. In your custom event handler, you would find related products and update some field on it (update counter?). This will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you I will try and do this, I assume this is what you are talking about?

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-subscriber-class

Comment: I have followed how it says to set this up in that documentation, but not totally sure what I should be doing with the "// ... do something with the Product" part, I have this https://pastebin.com/PzJpNVks but i'm not sure how to trigger it when I edit an entity?

Comment: You need no create a doctrine subscriber that listens to `postUpdate` event on `Category` entity. In the handler you would dispatch your own custom "category_updated" event.
The next step is to create your own custom event listener that would listen to "category_updated" event, find related `Product` entities and update some field on it. This, in turn, will invoke doctrine event on `Product` entity that will update your indexes. The same goes for supermarkets.
This solution would use both Doctrine events, and Symfony kernel events.